# React apollo no me reconoce el usuario al llamar al servicio en graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

tengo el siguiente problema:

Actualmente tengo configurada una app con react que consume un servicio a traves de graphql con apollo, probe en graphiql que el servicio funcionara (el user debe estar autenticado) pero ahora que pase las queries al front y llamo al servicio me retorna `user must be authenticated`.

Es como si al momento de hacer una peticion no me reconociera que el usuario esta autenticado, cuando revise en la condiguracion de `index.js` la variable `authLink` me pude percatar que el headers de `setContext` llega `undefined`:

```
// 1
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

// 2
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: config.url.API_URL
});

// 3
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});


// 4
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

El servicio en la vista se configuro de la siguiente manera:

```
// React
import React from 'react';

// Components
import SearchBar from '../../../components/searchbar';
import Books from '../../../components/books';

// React apollo
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import compose from 'lodash.flowright';

// Queries
import queries from './queries';

// Style
import './style.sass';

class BookHome extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            books: []
        }
        
        this.getBooks();
    }
    
    getBooks = () => {
        const { getBooks } = this.props;
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="books-home-container">
                <div className="books-header-home"></div>
                <SearchBar />
                <Books />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default compose(
    graphql(queries.getBooks, { name: 'getBooks' })
)(BookHome);
```

Y la variable queries que se llama de la vista (de arriba):

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const queries = {
    getBooks: gql`
    query {
        bookList {
            id
            coverImage
            title
            author
            rating
        }
    }
    `,
}

export default queries;
```

Comment: intenta agragar mayuscula `authorization: token ? Bearer ${token} : "",` a `Authorization: token ? Bearer ${token} : "",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

despues de ver el codigo con un colega pudimos llegar a la solucion hacian falta estas lineas en el metodo `current_user`:

```
# Aqui se agregan las tres lineas
session['init'] = true
session[:token] = request.headers['authorization'] if request.headers['authorization']
return unless session[:token]

crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base.byteslice(0..31))
token = crypt.decrypt_and_verify session[:token]
user_id = token.gsub('user-id:', '').to_i
User.find user_id
```

Comment: ¡Genial! Gracias por compartir la solución con la comunidad :)

Comment: De nada estimado!